Stepper Motor Microstepping, Why does look up table have more entries than available microsteps?
This questions is related to stepper motors. In my case, I have a stepper motor which can do 256 micro steps per full step. I understand that the driving circuit drives two coils out of phase with each other in order to achieve micro stepping and that there are 256 such micro steps in one full step. I understand that a Look up table (LUT) is commonly used for this and in my case a Sine table with 4×256 entries is used.
Observations: I can digitally read back the present sine wave entry. Every time I make one micro step I see the entry increase by 1 (or decrease by 1 if I go in the other direction).
My question is, if there are only 256 micro steps in a full step, then shouldn't the table have 256 entries (or 512 if there is a sign bit)?
Why would I need 4×256 table entries? To me this looks like I can track two full rotations in both directions.
Target stepper driver chip : https://www.analog.com/en/products/tmc2660.html
Also, for my motor I can do 200 full steps or 256×200 full steps in one full rotation. If I make these 256×200 microsteps these I can see one full rotation of my motor. So I am confident that each entry in the Sine table corresponds to 1 micro step value.

EDIT:
Below is a simplified picture of a bipolar stepper motor waveform. This is for full steps showing what each of the two coils (A coil and B coil) look like. Notice it takes 4 complete steps for any of the one waveforms to begin to repeat. You can imagine what micro-stepping might look like and that there are 4 full steps worth of microsteps in any one waveform. Hence, this is probably why the table entry has 4x256.


I've read your question twice and scanned the datasheet (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMC2660C_datasheet_rev1.03.pdf) for "sine". I don't see any reference to 4 x 256 sine table. I can't see where you are getting confused. Are you clear that if you have a table for 0° to 90° that 90° to 360° can be generated from that too?

See sheet 29. They refer to it as sine table (sheet 4) or microstep table (sheet 29).   Yes, that is clear. I don't know why the table would need to be 4 x 256 entries (256/4 + a polarity bit should be sufficient).

A "full step" is not the same thing as the number of poles in the motor. Remember, it takes four step pulses to advance a motor by one complete pole position, because there are four distinct coil states required to do it. Your driver is capable of dividing each state transition into 256 microsteps, and to simplify the logic, they use a separate set of lookup table entries for each transition.

I think this has the answer, restated each of the 4 wires will have an out of phase sine wave which produces the microstep motion. I believe this particular driver, as you said, is giving the user the perspective of one coil which will behave differently over the course of 4 full steps.

I'm glad you finally came back. I couldn't tell whether this was the type of information you were looking for.

I started to type a response but never pressed enter. sorry for the delay! But I greatly appreciate your answer.

From the comments:

See sheet 29. They refer to it as sine table (sheet 4) or microstep table (sheet 29). Yes, that is clear. I don't know why the table would need to be 4 x 256 entries (256/4 + a polarity bit should be sufficient)


Figure 1. Crude equivalent circuit with switches replacing the half-bridge drivers.
I haven't dug into the datasheets very much, but based on experience I would expect the following:

At some stage of the microstep sequence (say step 40) we require L1 on at $ sin(90 \times \frac {40}{256}) \times 248 = 60.26 \ \text{counts of 256 microsteps}$. The value in the table (column 2, row 8) is 60 so our maths looks OK.
Meanwhile L2 is following a cosine curve decreasing from max. For this we need to work backwards through the table by 40 steps which brings us to step 216 (column 7, row 24) which is 241 counts of 256 microsteps.
Now set the PWM of SW1 and SW4 to 60.
Set the PWM of SW6 and SW7 to 241.
It should give the required microstep power.
(Note that there is no need to PWM both the positive and negative switches. One could remain on until the polarity changes.)
When current is to be reversed the values are loaded into the other PWM registers for the opposing switches. There is no need for a polarity bit.

I haven't thought this through fully but I hope there's enough here to give you some clarification or suggest a possible way of effecting the required control.
